# Quick book integration with asp.net no apptoken detected

Tags: c#, asp.net, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

While I am accessing the Quick book intuit partner platform Request URL in my asp.net app, I am having the following issue:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
-<IntuitResponse requestId="d726443543j5h4377w49hj34734hd6" time="2013-10-11T05:32:55.345Z" xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">
-<Fault type="AUTHENTICATION">
-<Error code="3102">
<Message>message=No apptoken detected; errorCode=003102; statusCode=401</Message>
</Error>
</Fault>
</IntuitResponse>
```

How do I pass the apptoken?

Comment: Gold, please go through the documentation in detail to understand the 3 legged OAUTH process requried for making the sample app work. https://developer.intuit.com/

Comment: hi  nimisha shrivastava thanks for your response. Igot the Access Token and Access token secret. In that OAuth API Console the lean more leads to 404 page. Can you please kindly say me how can i use this token in my asp.net application and get the quick books details?.

Comment: Please download the sample apps from : https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/sample_code as Manas has mentioned. Set in your app keys and it will work. Is your app for QBO/QBD? Did you register for a trial version for QBO company?

Comment: Please go through the docs- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0010_getting_started/0010_signup Asking questions here will not help you if you do not read the content given in docs for getting the basic understanding of the API. I will report the 404 page to the docs team. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PFB the sample web.config. You need to setup consumerkey, consumerSecret and apptoken in this file.

https://github.com/IntuitDeveloperRelations/IPP_Sample_Code/blob/master/QuickbooksAPI/DotNet/WebForms%20application/QuickBooksApiDotNetWebFormsSampleApp/Web.config

.Net Sample apps are available here - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/sample_code

Using some RESTClients (like Rest client plugin of mozilla), please verify if your OAuth tokens are correct.

You can use ApiExplorer tool to call these endpoints.

https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer

Thanks

Comment: Hi Just accessing the link

Comment: Hi Just accessing the link <a href="https://qb.sbfinance.intuit.com/v3/company/123456789/account/1">Check</a>. But its not working

Comment: You can't simply access this API endpoint. 
You need to have proper OAuth tokens and proper content type set in HTTP request header. Use Java/.Net sdk to call this API endpoints.

In the API endpoint, relamId is mentioned is - 123456789 :). It is not a valid relam. I would suggest you to refer the following link - 
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0010_getting_started. 
Thanks

Comment: this is a actual link https://qb.sbfinance.intuit.com/v3/company/814166520/customer/1 and i have configure my the token in web config too.    <add key="consumerKey" value="qyprdPj9HqxlrkCHx7iPGOrt565k654" />
    <add key="consumerSecret" value="pxLYvjwGrukw47Id2IxHLK7w5KU76576575fvcfds5J4Ada" /> Still not working

Comment: Have you referred the following link ?
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0010_getting_started/0007_firstrequest

Are you using the sample app which intuit provides ? ConsumerKey and consumerSecret are not enough to call API endpoint. You need to get access token and accessSecret corresponding to the relamId. 

Please try to call these endpoints using ApiExplorer. Then if possible, setup the sample .net application. It will work.

Comment: Thank you very much for your very patient answers. I got the Access Token and Access token secret. In that OAuth API Console the lean more leads to 404 page. Can you please kindly say me how can i use this token in my asp.net application and get the quick books details?.

Comment: You might want to check my post in this SO thread - 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19179133/how-to-use-quick-book-invoice-api-in-asp-net

Hope it will be useful.

Thanks

Comment: Hi  Manas Mukherjee i have go through link. Thank you.