# Integration quickbooks desktop edition

Tags: asp.net, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I have installed Intuit QuickBooks Accountant Edition 2013 in my system. 
How can I integrate a QuickBooks desktop application with a asp.net application

Comment: What do you mean? What you are asking now is "How can I integrate a desktop application with a web site" which makes no sense. Are you asking how to read data from some web site into Quickbooks?

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos i have changed the question. I want to integrate quickbooks data with my asp.net application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check my post in the following SO thread - [How to use quick book invoice api in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19179133/how-to-use-quick-book-invoice-api-in-asp-net)

If you want to create non-saas custom solution, then you should use traditional QBSDK.
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0250_qb

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for use response. Currently i have installed the trail version. I have register it with my email ID. i have join to the https://developer.intuit.com. while i am clicking V3 QBD it shows 
You're logged in with an account that does not have a company with QuickBooks Desktop data synced to it. Please try another account.

Comment: You need to sync your QBD company file with Cloud. 
You can refer this article - http://support.quickbooks.intuit.com/support/Articles/INF12843

And docs links - 
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0500_quickbooks_windows/0400_data_synchronization

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0500_quickbooks_windows/0300_sync_manager

Thanks

Comment: How can i integrate the Quickbook using QuickBooks QBXML SDK. Can you please kindly provide me a link for QuickBooks QBXML SDK coding.

Comment: https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0250_qb/0050_documentation/sample_code

Comment: Hi, i am using WCWebService (desktop) from the above mentioned link. I have added the .qwc file into quickbooks web connecter. While i trying to update it asks for password. where can i get the password?

Comment: You generate the password when you build the server side of the Web Connector.